# Spring Boot Application is not running Flyway migrations on startup

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, database-migration, flyway

I have a Spring Boot Application with a couple Entity classes and I'm trying to implement database migrations with flyway. **It appears that, on startup, Spring Boot is not running flyway at all.**

Here is my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5555/mfidb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

spring.flyway.enabled=true
```

Here are the lines in my build.gradle that have something to do with flyway

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "6.4.1"
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'    
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.12')
}

flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5555/mfidb'
    user = 'postgres'
    password = 'postgres'
}
```

I am able to run my migrations by entering `gradle flywayMigrate -i` in the terminal.

But I want the migrations to run on startup.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is the console output when running the application

```
2020-05-05 11:55:59.022  INFO 50754 --- [           main] com.ubm.mfi.MfiApplication               : Starting MfiApplication on MacBook-Pro.local with PID 50754 (~/Downloads/mfi 5/build/classes/java/main started by will in ~/Downloads/mfi 5)
2020-05-05 11:55:59.024  INFO 50754 --- [           main] com.ubm.mfi.MfiApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-05 11:55:59.457  INFO 50754 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-05-05 11:55:59.495  INFO 50754 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 33ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-05-05 11:55:59.778  INFO 50754 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-05-05 11:55:59.783  INFO 50754 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-05 11:55:59.784  INFO 50754 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
2020-05-05 11:55:59.838  INFO 50754 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-05 11:55:59.838  INFO 50754 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 768 ms
2020-05-05 11:55:59.917  INFO 50754 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-05-05 11:55:59.944  INFO 50754 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-05-05 11:55:59.991  INFO 50754 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-05-05 11:56:00.051  INFO 50754 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-05 11:56:00.114  INFO 50754 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-05-05 11:56:00.124  INFO 50754 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
2020-05-05 11:56:00.545  INFO 50754 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-05-05 11:56:00.548  INFO 50754 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-05 11:56:00.818  WARN 50754 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-05-05 11:56:00.891  INFO 50754 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-05 11:56:01.005  INFO 50754 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-05-05 11:56:01.007  INFO 50754 --- [           main] com.ubm.mfi.MfiApplication               : Started MfiApplication in 2.255 seconds (JVM running for 2.983)
```

Here is the path to the data migrations

[image]

Comment: Can you also show where the migration scripts are kept in your project structure and what is the output you are getting in the console?

Comment: Added the running output on startup and image for path to migrations

Comment: Can you try by adding       spring.flyway.locations=classpath:/db/migration in property file

Comment: Didn't fix it @JiteshShivnani

Comment: Although @JiteshShivnani, I did turn logging on and got this error ```FlywayAutoConfiguration: Did not match: - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.flywaydb.core.Flyway' (OnClassCondition)```, but it is in my build.gradle

Comment: Can you try comparing gradle file with https://github.com/helloworlde/SpringBootCollection/blob/master/SpringBoot-Flyway/build.gradle.

Comment: Any Luck Here @WillHarrison

Comment: @geek, My configurations and structure was right, My dependencies weren't refreshing so the flyway dependencies were never pulled down. I was able to discover this was the problem using the logging tip in the selected answer below. I had to tell it to manually refresh my gradle dependencies to download the flyway classes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `logging.level.root=debug` your `application.properties` file to see detailed information during start application.

Also just add flyway user and password to `application.properties`.

```
spring.flyway.url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5555/mfidb'
spring.flyway.password=postgres
spring.flyway.user=postgres
```

if you dont need to run flyway from gradle, you can remove flyway config from `build.gradle`

Comment: This didn't fix it, but i turned logging on and I'm getting this ```FlywayAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.flywaydb.core.Flyway' (OnClassCondition)```

But it is there:

```implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'```

Comment: Try clean and build

Comment: It's still not seeing it. Is there something else I need to do to add it to the classpath or something like that?

Comment: I guess my dependencies weren't refreshing when doing a gradle clean build, so it never pulled the flyway dependencies. I had to manually tell it to refresh dependencies and that fixed it. Thanks for the logging level tip, that's what helped my find the solution.

Comment: It's not clear in the documentation what kind of URL the `spring.flyway.url` property accepts and I found it was only possible to make it work with a separate property/value for user name and password (rather than part of the URL)

Answer (score 6):

My dependencies weren't getting refreshed when i did a gradle clean build so the flyway source was never there. I had to manually refresh my dependencies in my IDE and it started working. Sad when you spend hours on something so simple. Giga's comment to change the logging level helped me to find the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In my case it, was a missing character in the filename of the flyway init script.

- Bad-Filename: V1_init.sql
- **Good-Filename**: V1__init.sql     (double '_')

I was missing an underscore in the filename, *it needs 2 instead of 1*.

Using spring-boot 2.6.7, my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate    # or 'none'
```

Resource-Folder

```
src/main/resources
- db/migration
    - V1__init.sql
```

Example of V1__init.sql

```
create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1;
CREATE TABLE person
(
    id   INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    age  INT,
    CONSTRAINT pk_person PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Described correctly in the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.migration-tool.flyway), but I recognised too late

Answer (score 2):

Your application.properties looks perfect to me.

I am using Flyway as well, it works like a charm and executes migrations on startup of my application. The only entry in my `build.gradle` related to flyway is the dependency

```
runtime("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
```

I think you should remove all other flyway related entries from `build.gradle`.

Comment: In Kotlin DSL it would be:     implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:{version}")

Answer (score 2):

In my case this is what happened:

I spent almost 4 hours to figure this out, My assumption was Spring JPA starter bring the flyway core dependency along with it. I didn't add the dependency for flyway-core explicitly. So if we dont do it spring boot flyway auto configuration will not give any error but just simply ignore the migration setup.

By tracing the auto configuration I figured out this, auto configuration ignoring the flyway setup if dependency not added manually rather than throwing exception using conditional annotation like this `@ConditionalOnMissingBean({Flyway.class})`

Comment: Did you add that to Application.java?

Comment: I didnt ad anything in the Application.java, Just added the `flyway-core` dependency into my pom.xml. spring jpa starter does not bring that dependency, i thought that was the case.

Comment: in my case, the accidental exclusion of `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` in Application.java ignore any migrations.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your script already run.

The trick is, once Flyway has succeeded in running the update script, it has created the table **flyway_schema_history**, that recorded that I have already run the create script successfully once.

When I tried to run the script second time, that was rejected but since the originally created table (in my case called 'bike') was deleted when the app shut down when run in **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop** mode previous time, I was getting the

`SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [bike]` Exception.

drop the **flyway_schema_history** table or delete a record corresponding to previous script run and roll again!

Answer (score 1):

After checking the SQL manually, here's what worked for me (using Spring Boot + Cloud):

important part in my build.gradle:

```
  implementation  'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
  implementation  'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
  implementation  'org.hibernate:hibernate-core'
  implementation  'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:7.0.1.Final'
```

no gradle plugins.  And in application.yml / application-local.yml:

```
spring:
  flyway:
    baseline-on-migrate: true

  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    open-in-view: true

  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/your_db
    username: your_db_user
    password: your_db_passwd
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
```

Note that you do not need the flyway specific config for DB user/url.  Spring Boot detects Flyway (or Liquibase if you were using that...) *on the classpath.* It then *uses the primary datasource.*  See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization .  Then the last trick is to make your first script **V2__init.sql** .  This is critical as the **baseline-on-migrate: true** bit creates the **flyway_schema_history** table and its action is the first thing, so version 1, or V1_ ie the first row... so your script won't go if it is **V1__init.sql** or whatever.  It will think it has already run.  It needs to be the next one, V2__init.sql or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

`spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `mysql-connector-java` dependencies are required for flyway to run. You can check that in debug output by enabling `logging.level.root=DEBUG` in your application properties.

Just add following dependencies to fix the issue:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.28</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: For Spring Boot 3.1.2 I had to add a dependency `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'` for Flyway to start working

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had the `db/migration` incorrectly spelled :)

Answer (score 1):

Tried all of the listed answers, and nothing helped.

Version incompatibility was the cause!
**Spring Boot 2.7.0** goes with **Flyway 8.5.13**

Comment: Flyway compatibility is the real issue with Spring Boot v2.x.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using maven, and solved this issue by running `mvn clean install`

Answer (score 0):

I found my way here after days of trying different permutations of configurations. For me when trying to upgrade all the way from `6.2.1` to `8.5.11` I simply needed to add `flyway.migrate()` to the before each in my integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had not named the migration correctly.
I had this name `v1_0_7__addEws.sql` but it should start with capital `V`
,ie, `V1_0_7__addEws.sql`

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-yourdatabase</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```